# How to process cogroup values?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am cogrouping two RDDs and I want to process its values. That is,

```
rdd1.cogroup(rdd2)
```

as a result of this cogrouping I get results as below:

```
(ion,(CompactBuffer(100772C121, 100772C111, 6666666666),CompactBuffer(100772C121)))
```

Considering this result I would like to obtain all distinct pairs. e.g.

For the key 'ion'

```
100772C121 - 100772C111
100772C121 - 666666666
100772C111 - 666666666
```

How can I do this in scala?

Comment: What if the second ``Seq`` is ``CompactBuffer(123)``? What do you do with that second ``Seq``? It is not clear from your example.

Comment: Actually i would like to get all distinct number pairs having the common key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like the following:

```
(l1 ++ l2).distinct.combinations(2).map { case Seq(x, y) => (x, y) }.toList
```

You would need to update `l1` and `l2` for your `CompactBuffer` fields. When I tried this locally, I get this (which is what I believe you want):

```
scala> val l1 = List("100772C121", "100772C111", "6666666666")
l1: List[String] = List(100772C121, 100772C111, 6666666666)

scala> val l2 = List("100772C121")
l2: List[String] = List(100772C121)

scala> val combine = (l1 ++ l2).distinct.combinations(2).map { case Seq(x, y) => (x, y) }.toList
combine: List[(String, String)] = List((100772C121,100772C111), (100772C121,6666666666), (100772C111,6666666666))
```

If you would like all of these pairs on separate rows, you can enclose this logic within a `flatMap`.

EDIT: Added steps per your example above.

```
scala> val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Array(("ion", "100772C121"), ("ion", "100772C111"), ("ion", "6666666666")))
rdd1: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String)] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:12

scala> val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(Array(("ion", "100772C121")))
rdd2: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String)] = ParallelCollectionRDD[1] at parallelize at <console>:12

scala>   val cgrp = rdd1.cogroup(rdd2).flatMap {
 |         case (key: String, (l1: Iterable[String], l2: Iterable[String])) =>
 |         (l1.toSeq ++ l2.toSeq).distinct.combinations(2).map { case Seq(x, y) => (x, y) }.toList
 |       }
 cgrp: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String)] = FlatMappedRDD[4] at flatMap at <console>:16

 scala> cgrp.foreach(println)

 ...

 (100772C121,100772C111)
 (100772C121,6666666666)
 (100772C111,6666666666)
```

EDIT 2: Updated again per your use case.

```
 scala> val cgrp = rdd1.cogroup(rdd2).flatMap {
 |      case (key: String, (l1: Iterable[String], l2: Iterable[String])) =>
 |           for { e1 <- l1.toSeq; e2 <- l2.toSeq; if (e1 != e2) } 
 |                yield if (e1 > e2) ((e1, e2), 1) else ((e2, e1), 1)
 |      }.reduceByKey(_ + _)

 ... 

 ((6666666666,100772C121),2)
 ((6666666666,100772C111),1)
 ((100772C121,100772C111),1)
```

Comment: As I understood from your solution, you manually put numbers into a list. What I would like to get is take them from cogrouped values. I mean how can I get thos values from val cg =rdd1.cogroup(rdd2). cg.values. ...?

Comment: I am getting less number of values than I expected. I was trying to understand the details of your suggested mapping. I will edit my question and give the answer if I can manage.

Comment: Ok i found the problem. Somehow (l1 ++ l2).combinations((2) part somehow changes the orders. e.g. when i put 1 for each pair and use it within reducebykey it gives like: (100772C121,666666666) 15, (666666666,100772C121) 26 ...But of course it must be 41 in total. Do you have an idea for this issue?

Comment: @user3198674 Did not realize you were trying to sum up the counts of each of the pairs. Please try the (re)edited code. I assumed you did not want tuples that contain the same element (e.g. (6666666666, 6666666666)). If you did, remove the conditional in the for-comprehension.

Comment: A small question. There are sometimes some key values appearing only on one side which gives such a reuslt based on cogroup: (f e,(CompactBuffer(100772C111),CompactBuffer())). Can I filter such cases? For ex. can I add a condition to if e.g. if (e1.length > 1 && e2.length > 1)

Comment: @user3198674 Yep, a filter works best here. Perhaps, a more idiomatic way to apply it would be to define a function that takes a list and return the following `list.filter(_.nonEmpty)`. Then call this function within the for-comprehension for both input lists.